# como puedo mostrar la información en columna y fila en php

Tags: php, css, html5

Estoy trabajando en mi primer proyecto y estoy mandando la información desde la base pero me muestra todo solo en una fila y lo demás queda en blanco.

[image: así es como me muestra la información]

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos ";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conexion));
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    ?>

    <div class="bg0 m-t-23 p-b-140">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row isotope-grid">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women">
                    <div class="block2">

                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="images/product-01.jpg" alt="IMAGEN PRODUCTO">
                        </div>        
                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="detalles.php?idproducto=<?php echo $record['idproducto'];?>" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    <?php echo $record['tituloproducto']; ?>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php echo $record['subtituloproducto']; ?>
                                </a>

                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    $<?php echo $record['precio']; ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: No sabemos que CSS estas usando, parece una mezcla de boostrap con alguna otra cosa, o bien algo personalizado.  Si no pones la referencia de los estilos CSS que estas usando poco podemos ayudarte. Aún así, veo que usas "container" y "row", que normalmente no se usan asi... es decir, lo usual es usar el "container" una vez por documento y no en un bucle (mira de sacarlo de ahi), y el "row" lo que te indica "normalmente" es "fila", es decir, te crea una fila por cada elemento del bucle, por eso no lo ves en columnas seguramente. Tu problema es más de CSS y HTML que de otra cosa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me funciono muy bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de dos maneras. En caso de que estes utilizando `Bootstrap`, podrás hacer de la manera en la que lo planteas, pero tendrás que cambiar un poco la estructura. Otra manera de hacerlo sería utilizando una tabla, pero no va a quedar responsivo para todos los dispositivos.

**Con Bootstrap:**

```
<div class="bg0 m-t-23 p-b-140">

        <div class="container">

           <div class="row isotope-grid">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos ";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conexion));
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    ?>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-b-35 isotope-item women">
                    <div class="block2">

                        <div class="block2-pic hov-img0">
                            <img src="images/product-01.jpg" alt="IMAGEN PRODUCTO">
                        </div>        
                        <div class="block2-txt flex-w flex-t p-t-14">
                            <div class="block2-txt-child1 flex-col-l ">
                                <a href="detalles.php?idproducto=<?php echo $record['idproducto'];?>" class="stext-104 cl4 hov-cl1 trans-04 js-name-b2 p-b-6">
                                    <?php echo $record['tituloproducto']; ?>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php echo $record['subtituloproducto']; ?>
                                </a>

                                <span class="stext-105 cl3">
                                    $<?php echo $record['precio']; ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            
        

    <?php } ?>  
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Lo que tienes que hacer, es crear un div para cada registro de la base de datos, tu estabas creando una línea para cada uno.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me funciono muy bien